# How to access anonymous type projected in Linq query in the next chained extension method?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have a collection of `Schemas`, where each Schema has `Name`, `Id` and several other properties. I need to project just the `Name` and `Id` of every `Schema` and thus I am creating an anonymous type in the LINQ query as follows:

```
from s in db.Schemas
select new { Id = s.SchemaId, Name = s.Name}
```

I need to convert the above anonymous type projected via the `Select` query operator to a `Dictionary<int,string>` and for that I need to add a further extension method overload to the above query as follows:

```
(from s in db.Schemas
select new { Id = s.SchemaId, Name = s.Name})
.ToDictionary<TSource,int,string>()
```

Now, how can I access the anonymous type in the `ToDictionary()` overload?

What should I replace `TSource` type parameter with?

I have other methods to do this, but I am wondering if it can be done in this way by accessing the anonymous type. Any other nice method to do this are also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can elide the type arguments completely.

```
(from s in db.Schemas
select new { Id = s.SchemaId, Name = s.Name})
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p => p.Name);
```

The compiler can infer them for you.

In fact, you may be able to do this in a single step:

```
db.Schemas.ToDictionary(s => s.SchemaId, s => s.Name);
```

or at least by sticking with one type of LINQ syntax:

```
db.Schemas
    .Select(s => new { Id = s.SchemaId, Name = s.Name })
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p => p.Name);
```

Comment: Nit: parameters => arguments. (Or better, type arguments.)

Comment: @Jon Of course, thanks. Also this is possibly the fastest I've ever been upvoted.

Comment: Even if for some reason the OP wants to keep the `Select`, it would probably be cleaner to use extension method syntax throughout - query expressions with *just* select and/or where are usually simpler as "normal" calls...

Comment: @Rawling is it really equivalent? `db.Schemas.ToDictionary(s => s.SchemaId, s => s.Name);`? Won't the query be on the full row instead of being only on two fields?

Comment: @xanatos That's a very good point; it depends on whether the LINQ-to-Entities provider is clever enough to only ask from SQL for the two columns it needs, which I'll admit I don't know.

Comment: @Rawling can it do it? `ToDictionary()` is `Enumerable.ToDictionary()`, so all the LINQ-to-Entities sees is a `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: @xanatos That'd settle it then, in which case the first or third answers should work if projecting the data down is important.